# Internally tangential circles

Tags: geometry

Two circles are internally tangent at $T$. $AB$ is a chord of the outer circle that is also tangent to the inner circle at $P$.

How can one go about showing that $\angle ATP = \angle BTP$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a proof.

Draw the tangent at $T$ and label two points on it $C$ and $D$ with $C$ on the "$A$" side and $D$ on the other side of $T$. Let $AT$ intersect with the smaller circle at S.

Then

$\angle ATC = \angle TPS$

$\angle BTD = \angle BAT$

$\angle APS = \angle PTA$

and the conclusion follows.